# How to set top-left corner icon of an eclipse 4 APP

Tags: eclipse, rcp, e4

I tried to set a icon at the top-left corner of the shell for one eclipse 4.2 APP. I already set the branding images, but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

The branding images in the *.product file are not picked up by e4.

There are two ways to get an icon into the corner of your window.

1) Set the "Icon URI" attribute of your Window in the *.e4xmi

2) Set the default icons(s) using the JFace Window Singleton API

```
Window.setDefaultImages(new Image[] {...});
```

P.S. The bug mentioned in the previous answer has been fixed:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=280825

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is bug which is already reported. You can set the top left icon only but fetching the active shell and perform setimage method.